# Create Geographical Grid based on data using K-D Trees (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, geolocation, gis, kdtree

For my research, I need to divide the geographical area of a city (i.e.Chicago or New York) using a grid. Later, I have data points consisting of GPS longitude and latitude location that I want to associate to its corresponding cell in the grid.

The simplest way to do this is dividing the space into squared cells of same size. However, this will lead to cells with very few points in non-populated (rural areas) areas and cells with a high number of points (city centre). In order to have a more fair representation and the relation between the number of points and cell size, an adaptative grid that create cells of size based on data density would be a better option.

I came across [this paper](http://stephenroller.com/research/roller_etal_emnlp2012.pdf) that utilise a K-D tree to do the space partition and retrieve the cells from the nodes. However, I cannot find any [implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) (in python) that does that. Many of the implementations out there only index data points in the tree to perform Nearest Neighbour search, but they not provide code to extract the polygon-rectangles that k-d tree generates.

For example, given the following image:

[image]

My resulting grid will contain 5 cells (node1 to node5) where each cell contains the associated data points.

Any idea on how to do that?

Anyone knows any implementation?

Many thanks,
David